# Facebook login works on desktop but not mobile

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, mobile, facebook-php-sdk

When I try to use Facebook login for my website (*it's how we signup users*) it works perfectly on a desktop, but when I try on a mobile device the oath dialog says "`An error occurred. Please try again later.`"

**Things I have tried/checked:**

- The `appId` and `secret` are all correct with what is in https://developers.facebook.com/
- I'm using the PHP SDK for logging in.
- I'm using `$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,user_birthday,user_about_me','redirect_uri' => $loginURL));` to generate the login URL.

Does anyone know how else I might debug this issue? Or know what might cause this?

Comment: are you using the same domain? and the same url? The Page Tab URL: and the Secure Page Tab URL: must be the same for desktop and mobile

Comment: @FabioAntunes Yeah, everything is the same.

Comment: On your mobile are you logged on facebook already, or try this way logout facebook on desktop and try to acces your app

Comment: @FabioAntunes When I was trying it earlier, I was logged in. I just logged out and retried it. One thing I noticed was it gave me the "login page" for a desktop, and not a mobile device. Then, after I logged in, I got the same error. Logging out of Facebook on desktop, then trying, didn't seem to make a difference either. Thoughts?

Comment: @FabioAntunes I did notice my "base_facebook.php" file was out of date since an update they recently put out, but it still seems to give me that error. It didn't change anything after I updated it.

Comment: could you tell me wich are the url's for the mobile and for the desktop? another thing could you echo the login url

Comment: What mobile device is it?

Comment: @FabioAntunes Okay, so I got it working, sort of. I used `'display' => 'touch'` in the `getLoginUrl` parameters if it's a mobile device (codeigniter's `$this->agent->is_mobile()`). That makes it work, however, it seems like a bad work-around, because sometimes that may not work to detect if it's mobile or not, and then it would still just give that "An error occurred. Please try again later." error. What do you think?

Comment: @Zach I usually use javascript sdk on mobile web apps, so I'm guessing the error is somewhere on your getloginurl

Comment: If I recall correctly codeigniters is_mobile() doesn't differentiate between tablets and smartphones. So if you only want to target smartphones you may want to use a third party library like php-mobile-detect

Comment: What @Jeemusu said it's true, is_mobile() is both for tablets and for mobile phones

Comment: @FabioAntunes Okay, I will switch to that library. So maybe try the Javascript SDK for logging in?

Comment: I'm not saying you should switch what I'm saying is that I use the javascript sdk when users access to my app with mobile devices (tablets and phones). If You need some help using the javascript SDK I could help you. But the php SDK should work what I suggest you to do before changing to javascript SDK is instrad of using php sdk to build your login url try building manually.Something like this <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=(app_id))&redirect_uri=(app_url)&scope=email,user_about_me,user_birthday" target="_top"> Login</a>

Comment: @FabioAntunes Okay, I'll try that before I switch everything! Thanks!